# Rounding Total Price Adjuster Commerce not working correctly

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, adjusters, rounding

I have this adjuster which should round prices to the nearest 5 decimal.
I am pretty sure it had been working, and now it does not anymore.

I tried to debug, but I don't find the error.

In my commerce project, the normal item price does not have to be rounded,
but I apply discounts via another adjuster, and then the itemprice gets really
uneven.

When I dump $roundedPrice it always gives me the actual price of one item
(not rounded)

My goal is to round the final order price which the cart has.
Alternatively, rounding the subtotal of one item would be an option.

What is not right in this adjuster?

---

```
class RoundingAdjuster extends Component implements AdjusterInterface
{
  public const CENTS_TO_ROUND_DOWN_TO = 5;

  public function adjust(Order $order): array
  {

    $factor = 100 / self::CENTS_TO_ROUND_DOWN_TO;
    $roundedPrice = floor($order->totalPrice * $factor) / $factor;
    $difference = $roundedPrice - $order->totalPrice;
   
 
    if ($difference >= 0) {
      return [];
    }

    $adjustment = new OrderAdjustment();
    $adjustment->type = 'discount';
    $adjustment->name = 'Rundung';
    $adjustment->sourceSnapshot = ['data' => 'value'];
    $adjustment->amount = $difference;
    $adjustment->setOrder($order);

    return [$adjustment];

  }
}
```